# How to get the total count of number in a range 10-70, 71-80,81-100 in a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
var projects = [
{
"DisciplineId": "10",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"PhaseId": "103",
},
{
"DisciplineId": "20",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"PhaseId": "102",
},
{
"DisciplineId": "30",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"PhaseId": "102",
},
{
"DisciplineId": "71",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"PhaseId": "102",
},
{
"DisciplineId": "81",
"DisciplineName": "General",
"PhaseId": "102",
},
]
```

**Expected Result:**
Less than 70: Answer is 3 (ie., 10,20 and 30 in DisciplineId)
Range 70-80: Answer is 1 (ie., 71 in DisciplineId)
Range > 81: Answer is 1 (ie., 81 in DisciplineId)

Any suggestion to achieve through jquery/javascript or angularjs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried some methods and no clue, thats reason posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the simple way using jquery to loop the json array

```
 var lessThan70Cnt = 0;
 var cnt70To80 = 0;
 var greaterThan80 = 0;

 $.each(data, function(index, item){
   if(parseInt(item.DisciplineId) < 70){
      lessThan70Cnt++;
   }
   else if(parseInt(item.DisciplineId) > 70 && parseInt(item.DisciplineId) < 80){
      cnt70To80++;
   }
   else if(parseInt(item.DisciplineId) > 80){
      greaterThan80++;
   }
 });
```

Comment: People still use jQuery?

Comment: Thank you Neel, this works.

Comment: @doodlemeister - yeah, jQuery is great, but completely overkill here!
`data.forEach(function(item) {if(+item.DisciplineId < 70) lessThan70Cnt++; else if(+item.DisciplineId <= 80) cnt70To80++; else greaterThan80++;});`

Comment: @doodlemeister - Jquery/javascript is the basis of all latest client side technologies.

Comment: @Neel = JS, sure.  jQuery, not even close. It's the basis of nothing except the codebase written by devs who still use it for whatever reason.